How should I show that the solution of this equation can be expressed as the given equation? (Please check my work.)
Consider the nonlinear integro-differential equation $$\frac{dx}{dt}=-\lambda x(t)+\epsilon x(t)\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t-s)x(s)ds, \lvert \epsilon \rvert<<1, x(0)=A,$$ where $\lambda$ is a positive constant and $f(z)$ is a sufficiently well-behaved function. Use perturbation methods to show that the solution of this equation can be expressed as $$x(t)=x_{0}(t)+\epsilon x_{1}(t)+\epsilon^{2}x_{2}(t)+O(\epsilon^{3})$$ where $$x_{0}(t)=Ae^{-\lambda t},\\ x_{1}(t)=x_{0}(t)\int_{0}^{t}du\int_{0}^{\infty}f(u-s)x_{0}(s)ds,\\ x_{2}(t)=e^{-\lambda t}\int_{0}^{t}e^{\lambda u}du\int_{0}^{\infty}f(u-s)(x_{0}(u)x_{1}(s)+x_{0}(s)x_{1}(u))ds.$$
If $f(z)=e^{-\mu\lvert z \rvert}, \mu>0$, show that $x(t)=Ae^{-\lambda t}(1+\frac{A\epsilon}{\mu^{2}-\lambda^{2}}(\frac{2\mu}{\lambda}(1-e^{-\lambda t})-\frac{\mu+\lambda}{\mu}(1-e^{-\mu t})))+O(\epsilon^{2})$, for $\mu\neq\lambda$, and $x(t)=Ae^{-\lambda t}(1+\frac{A\epsilon}{2\lambda^{2}}(3(1-e^{-\lambda t})-2\lambda te^{-\lambda t}))+O(\epsilon^{2})$, for $\mu=\lambda$.
Here's my work: Proof:
Consider the nonlinear integro-differential equation $\frac{dx}{dt}=-\lambda x(t)+\epsilon x(t)\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t-s)x(s)ds, \lvert \epsilon \rvert<<1, x(0)=A$, where $\lambda$ is a positive constant and $f(z)$ is a sufficiently well-behaved function.
Let $\epsilon=0$.
Then the unperturbed equation is $\frac{dx}{dt}=-\lambda x(t)$ with the initial condition $x(0)=A$.
This gives $\frac{dx}{dt}=-\lambda x(t)\implies \frac{dx}{x}=-\lambda dt\implies \int \frac{dx}{x}=-\lambda\int dt\implies ln\lvert x \rvert=-\lambda t+C\implies x=Ce^{-\lambda t}$ where $C$ is a constant of integration.
Since $x(0)=A$, it follows that $A=C$, so we have $x=Ae^{-\lambda t}$.
Hence, $x_{0}(t)=Ae^{-\lambda t}$.
Applying the perturbation theory produces $x(t)=x_{0}(t)+\epsilon x_{1}(t)+\epsilon^{2}x_{2}(t)+O(\epsilon^{3})$ for $\lvert \epsilon \rvert<<1$.
By direct substitution of this expansion $x(t)=x_{0}(t)+\epsilon x_{1}(t)+\epsilon^{2}x_{2}(t)+O(\epsilon^{3})$ into the original equation, we get $\frac{d}{dt}(x_{0}(t)+\epsilon x_{1}(t)+\epsilon^{2}x_{2}(t)+O(\epsilon^{3}))=-\lambda(x_{0}(t)+\epsilon x_{1}(t)+\epsilon^{2}x_{2}(t)+O(\epsilon^{3}))+\epsilon(x_{0}(t)+\epsilon x_{1}(t)+\epsilon^{2}x_{2}(t)+O(\epsilon^{3}))\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t-s)(x_{0}(s)+\epsilon x_{1}(s)+\epsilon^{2}x_{2}(s)+O(\epsilon^{3}))ds$
for $\lvert \epsilon \rvert<<1, x(0)=A,$ where $\lambda$ is a positive constant and $f(z)$ is a sufficiently well-behaved function.
From the work above, how should I find $x_{1}(t), x_{2}(t)$ so I can match them with the given equations and how should I show that $x(t)=...$ by using the $f(z)=...$ function for the second part of this question/problem?

HINTS:
Expand parentheses in your last equation and group together terms with the same power of $\epsilon$. For example, for $\epsilon^1$ you get $$\frac{dx_1}{dt}=-\lambda x_1+x_0(t)\int_0^\infty f(t-s)x_0(t) ds$$
It is easy to see that you can just ignore the first term (it is absorbed into $x_0$), so you are to integrate left and right hand sides from $0$ to $t$:
$$x_1(t)=\int_0^t\left(x_0(u)\int_0^\infty f(u-s)x_0(u)ds\right)du$$

Isn't it $...f(t-s)x_{0}(s)ds$?

So I've got $\frac{dx_{2}}{dt}=-\lambda x_{2}(t)+x_{0}(t)\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t-s)x_{1}(s)ds+x_{1}(t)\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t-s)x_{0}(s)ds$ after by grouping the same terms with the same powers of $\epsilon$ together. However, how should I integrate from here in order to show/prove that $x_{2}(t)=e^{-\lambda t}\int_{0}^{t}e^{\lambda u}du\int_{0}^{\infty}f(u-s)(x_{0}(u)x_{1}(s)+x_{0}(s)x_{1}(u))ds$? Do I ignore the first term, $-\lambda x_{2}(t)$ again?

Yes. Notice that is included in $x_0$

So how should I integrate $\frac{dx_{2}}{dt}=x_{0}(t)\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t-s)x_{1}(s)ds+x_{1}(t)\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t-s)x_{0}(s)ds$ with respect to $u$ from $0$ to $t$?

Yes. Change $t$ to $u$ first.

Okay, I've got $\frac{dx_{2}}{dt}=x_{0}(u)\int_{0}^{\infty}f(u-s)x_{1}(s)ds+x_{1}(u)\int_{0}^{\infty}f(u-s)x_{0}(s)dx$. And then?

I've got $x_{2}(t)=\int_{0}^{t}(x_{0}(u)\int_{0}^{\infty}f(u-s)x_{1}(s)ds+x_{1}(u)\int_{0}^{\infty}f(u-s)x_{0}(s))du$. How to show/prove that $x_{2}(t)=e^{-\lambda t}\int_{0}^{t}e^{\lambda u}du\int_{0}^{\infty}f(u-s)(x_{0}(u)x_{1}(s)+x_{0}(s)x_{1}(u))ds$ from here?
